# Adding choices but not showing in the selectbox

Tags: python, django, django-models

I am trying to add categories in my blog project. So that whenever user post a blog he will add category also but in the select box it is not showing I tried this :

```
from django import forms
from .models import Post,Category,Comment

choices = Category.objects.all().values_list('name','name')

choice_list = []

for item in choices:
    choice_list.append(item)

class PostForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Post
        fields = ('title','title_tag','author','category','body','snippet','header_image')
        widgets = {
            'title' : forms.TextInput(attrs={'class':'form-control','placeholder':'Title of the Blog'}),
            'title_tag' : forms.TextInput(attrs={'class':'form-control','placeholder':'Title tag of the Blog'}),
            'author' : forms.TextInput(attrs={'class':'form-control','value':'','id':'elder','type':'hidden'}),
            'category' : forms.Select(choices=choice_list, attrs={'class':'form-control','placeholder':"blog's category"}),
            'body' : forms.Textarea(attrs={'class':'form-control','placeholder':'Body of the Blog'}),
            'snippet' : forms.Textarea(attrs={'class':'form-control'}),
        }
```

Here Category model contains my categories

My models.py

```
class Post(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    header_image = models.ImageField(
        null=True, blank=True, upload_to="images/")
    title_tag = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    author = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    body = RichTextField(blank=True, null=True)
    post_date = models.DateField(auto_now_add=True)
    category = models.CharField(max_length=25, default='coding')
    snippet = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    likes = models.ManyToManyField(User, related_name='blog_posts')

    def total_likes(self):
        return self.likes.count

    def __str__(self):
        return self.title + ' | ' + str(self.author)

    def get_absolute_url(self):
        # return reverse("article_detail", args={str(self.id)})      return to self blog
        return reverse("home")
```

Comment: as soon as your code starts the choice_list is generated and used as is, i.e. unalterable. I guess the queryset for Category should be placed in a function called by class PostForm or some similar way. Then choice_list will dynamically change itself in runtime.

Comment: what would be the code of it

Comment: **category** is char field or foreign key ??

Comment: It is char field